# How search in relation many to many in Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

```
User:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    username:
      type: string(255)

Group:
  tableName: group_table
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
  relations:
    Users:
      foreignAlias: Groups
      class: User
      refClass: GroupUser

GroupUser:
  columns:
    group_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
  relations:
    Group:
      foreignAlias: GroupUsers
    User:
      foreignAlias: GroupUsers


DB:
USER:
id | username
1  | john
2  | kate
3  | alan

GROUP:
id  | name
1   | admin
2   | mod
3   | kate (!)

USERGROUP:

id_user | id_group
1       | 1
2       | 1
1       | 2
3       | 3
3       | 2
2       | 3
```

I would like make search system. I will search for example word: "KATE".
How can i search in many to many table for KATE?

In input search i write "KATE". I must use WHERE LIKE in Doctrine.
How this query must look?
This should show me all user with username Kate and all user for group Kate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DQL ammounts to the following...

Search for Users named kate or Users in the Group kate, returning user and groups

`FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.Groups g WHERE u.username LIKE 'KATE' OR g.name LIKE 'KATE'`

so...

```
$qry = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('User u')
  ->leftJoin("u.Groups g")
  ->where("u.username LIKE ? OR g.name LIKE ?", array('KATE','KATE'));
```

Comment: thanks! i must give KATE for all "?". I would like several "?" in where, and only KATE as Parameter.